# AuthenticationContextDelegate is not getting called from the ADAL library

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory

An example of the implementation for the [ADAL library for Windows Phone 8.1](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/06/16/adal-for-windows-phone-8-1-deep-dive/) can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1)

To display the Azure Login page for the user you call the `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAndContinue` method. After the login process it should do a callback to the `AuthenticationContextDelegate`.

```
AuthenticationContext _authenticationContext = AuthenticationContext.CreateAsync(authority).GetResults();
_authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAndContinue(resource, clientId, redirectUri, authenticationContextDelegate);

AuthenticationContextDelegate authenticationContextDelegate= new AuthenticationContextDelegate(AuthContextDelegateMethod);

public static void AuthContextDelegateMethod(AuthenticationResult result)
{
     // Never called
}
```

The `AuthContextDelegateMethod` is not getting called even after a successful login.

Is there any reason why the `AuthenticationContextDelegate` is not called, and any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with the ADAL library not working and not calling the `AuthContextDelegateMethod`

The firts thing was to understand how the [`AndContinue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn631755.aspx) methods work, once you understand this the rest make a lot of sense.

#### App.xaml.cs

In your **App.xaml.cs** you need to add the `OnActivate` method which works with the `ContinuationManager`; this is where the app enters after the Azure login returns.

```
ContinuationManager _continuationManager;
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    _continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

    var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (continuationEventArgs != null)
    {
        IWebAuthenticationContinuable azure = GetIWebAuthenticationContinuableInstance();
        _continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, azure);        
    }
}
```

The `GetIWebAuthenticationContinuableInstance` should return the same instance of the `IWebAuthenticationContinuable` that called `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAndContinue`; I had some issues when you try to give it a `new` instance (didn't work), in this answer it is called `AzureLoginClass` below.

#### ContinuationManager

Then in the [ContinuationManager](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1/blob/master/TodoListClient/ContinuationManager.cs) I added the following function *(which is an adaptation of `Continue(IContinuationActivatedEventArgs args, Frame rootFrame)`)*:

```
internal void Continue(IContinuationActivatedEventArgs args, IWebAuthenticationContinuable wabPage)
{
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("args");

    if (this.args != null && !handled)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't set args more than once");

    this.args = args;
    this.handled = false;
    this.id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (wabPage == null)
        return;

    switch (args.Kind)
    {
        case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
            break;

        case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
            break;

        case ActivationKind.PickFolderContinuation:
            break;

        case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
            
            if (wabPage != null)
            {
                wabPage.ContinueWebAuthentication(args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I needed to do this because I implemented my `IWebAuthenticationContinuable` as part of a class and the given implementations give preference to an AppicationPage.

#### AzureLoginClass

Then in your implementation of `IWebAuthenticationContinuable`'s `ContinueWebAuthentication` you need to call the `ContinueAcquireTokenAsync`

```
public class AzureLoginClass : IWebAuthenticationContinuable
{
  
   public void CallAzureLogin
   {
       _authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAndContinue(resource, clientId, redirectUri, AuthContextDelegateMethod);
   }

   private void AuthContextDelegateMethod(AuthenticationResult result)
   {
      // Is now called when ContinueAcquireTokenAsync is called
   }
   public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
   {
      AuthenticationResult result = await _authenticationContext .ContinueAcquireTokenAsync(args);
   }
}
```

When `ContinueAcquireTokenAsync` is called it gives a callback to `AuthContextDelegateMethod`. This is however not called if `result.ErrorDescription` is `"User canceled authentication"`, so if you need this you should cater extra for it.